# MVC4 Razor Appending ID to a url using route.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I just cant achieve my goal of getting an id to appear in a URL. Here is an example of what I have done so far.

Here is my BlogController:

```
 public ActionResult BlogPost(int hiddenBlogId)
    {

        TempData["id"] = hiddenBlogId;
        return View(_repository);
    }
```

Here is my route.config:

```
routes.MapRoute(            
            "MyBlog", // Route name
            "blog/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "blogpost", id = @"0|-?[1-9]\d*" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I am completely missing the point somewhere. How can I pick up the parameter which went into my method/action BlogPost and then display it in the output URL.

http://www.mydomain/controller/id

It's so that in the end I should be able to display the title for each blog. I'm using an ID just for simplicity for now. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your route definition says that the third value is called `id`, but you are trying to bind `hiddenBlogId` in the method. The two names need to match. Change the `hiddenBlogId` action method parameter to `id`, or map a new route with the `{hiddenBlogId}` placeholder.

Comment: If you just enter http://www.mydomain/blog/blogpost/5 do you get a value for the id parameter? Your maproute may be the problem. Try making the `id` optional and removing the `action="blogpost"` part.

Comment: Ah...sorry misread that part. Try `routes.MapRoute(            
            "MyBlog", 
            "blog/{id}", 
                new { controller = "Blog", action = "blogpost", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );`  I usually prefer to put a default value on the id in this case but there are several ways to handle that.

Comment: Thats not worked. I have another view served by the blogcontroller which is accessed first called bloglist. Thanks for all the advice you have given me it has been very nice of you.

Comment: I just cant get this to work at all. Anyone have any clue? I've been doing this for so long now and it's such a simple idea.